# Biztalk 2013 Agreement not applied

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk-2013

I have set up an agreement. I have a send port to a file using EdiSend as send pipeline option so we may have a copy of the EDI file we have received from an FTP receive location. The EDI that comes through has BTS-SENDER and RECEIVE-PARTNER in the ISA line.

I assume this means that Fallback settings were used and not my agreement. I this a correct assumption?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Those are the default values for the fallback settings.  You can disable fallback settings (right click Parties -> X12 fallback settings, and uncheck "Enable Fallback Settings") to prevent them from being used at all.

It's likely there's a problem in your agreement settings somewhere - you've excluded (or forgot to include) the transaction you're trying to process, or some other setting is not properly configured in the interchange or transaction set settings.